# Dreamweaver will not select android os

Tags: android-emulator, dreamweaver, phonegap-plugins

**Another emulator issue**

I had the same "easy install" issues as everyone else, and like everyone else, I did the 11.5.1 update, run as administrator, use Droid API 8 (which was my original plan anyway) and yet when I am in the native applications setting, i cannot select any droid OS whatsoever. even clicking the manage avd is of no use. Everything works fine in eclipse, but dreamweaver and phonegap had the perfect template and "ease of use" required for the app i am wanting to build for my gameing community.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem with compiling your files.

You can use **https://build.phonegap.com/** Which will help you build your all html and javascript files.

Remember to add config.xml in the folder and create the .zip archive for uploading directly from the files and do not add those files in a folder to create an zip archive.